# EF CORE Optimistic concurrency without timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I'm working with a  bounch of entities each of them  having several properties. 
Each property is involved in  optimistic concurrency check on saving. 
I prefer avoid using of timestamp as I should add the field on each tables, Im working with a legacy database and  I don't want to make any changes on it.
The solution adopted rely on calling  IsConcurrencyToken in the  modelBuilder

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity1>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.Property(e => e.Property1).IsConcurrencyToken;
                    entity.Property(e => e.Property2).IsConcurrencyToken;
                    entity.Property(e => e.Property3).IsConcurrencyToken;


                    entity.Property(e => e.PropertyN).IsConcurrencyToken;
                });         
             }
```

but do I really need to explicitly call `IsConcurrencyToken` for every properties? Is there any chance to configure my entities to automatically include every properties in the concurrency check?

Comment: *but do I really need to set call IsConcurrencyToken for every properties?* That's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @GertArnold - no it is not... It is a technical question based on precise enough requirements.

Comment: Im not asking opinion about the choice to include all properties in the concurrency check, but if there is a faster way than explicitly set it property by property to do it.

Comment: It is opinion as long as we don't have more details. What about fields of which the current db value doesn't matter at update, or fields that won't ever be updated after create (as per business logic)? What about computed fields of which the value changed while editing? No need to mark them as concurrency token. And then there may be fields that should have a "last one wins" strategy (f.e. "LastSeenBy"). IMO marking all properties as concurrency token is too simple. It may have to be a per-entity operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any chance to configure my entities to automatically include every properties in the concurrency check?

Yes.  You can iterate over all your entities and properties in OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var prop in entity.GetProperties())
        {
            prop.IsConcurrencyToken = true;
        }
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Browne for the suggestion.

As I want to be able to enable concurrency entity by entity I wrapped the code in extension method

```
  public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> EnableConcurrency<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entityTypeBuilder) where TEntity : class
        {
            var entity = entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
            foreach (var prop in entity.GetProperties())
            {
                prop.IsConcurrencyToken = true;
            }
            return entityTypeBuilder;
        }
```

and Im going to use it like that

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.EnableConcurrency();
            });
```